# Skrollr example not working in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, skrollr

I have been putting together a site based off of a the skrollr example code found here : http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/classic.html

I noticed some issues with this example in IE 9 where the images are not being displayed at all. Has anyone ran into this issue before?

One thing that I read was that data-target does not work in IE 8 without an additional plugin, but as far as I know, that should not be an issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's using `translate3d`. Simply replace every `translate3d(a,b,c)` with `translate(a,b)`